# Python object isn't being created as normal even though I have created it as normal within the same function (doubly linked list)

Tags: python, object, nodes, doubly-linked-list

I've created a doubly linked list and I'm having trouble with a function that swaps the first node with the last node, the second node with the second from last, etc. I'm creating various functions within the doubly linked list class (LDL). The problem comes with trying to create a node object. However it's strange as I have created the node objects without problem even within the same function. Here's the code:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data, nextLeft=None, nextRight=None):
        self.data = data
        self.nextLeft = nextLeft
        self.nextRight = nextRight


class LDL:
    def __init__(self, head=None):
        self.head = head


    def insertAtEnd(self, dataToInsert):
        ...


    def reverseSwap(self):
        nodeFirst = self.head  # THE PROBLEM OBJECT
        nodeCurrent = self.head
        nodeLast = Node(None)
        counter = 0

        while nodeCurrent.nextRight is not None:
            nodeCurrent = nodeCurrent.nextRight
            conter += 1

        for i in range(0, int(cont/2)):
            temp = nodeFirst.data
            nodeFirst.data = nodeLast.data  # THE LINE OF THE ERROR
            nodeLast.data = temp

            nodeFirst = nodeFirst.nextRight
            nodeLast = nodeLast.nextLeft
```

When I try to run this I get the error:

> nodeFirst.data = nodeLast.data

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'data'

However I knew this was coming as I can see while coding that it's not recognised as a Node object, because it doesn't offer to autofill *nodeFirst.data* or *nodeFirst.nextLeft* etc.

I have tried setting *nodeFirst = nodeCurrent*, I have tried placing it at various other parts of the code, I have tried different names, but I can't get it to work.

**EDIT**: I should point out that *nodeCurrent = self.head* works fine and as intended. This is also the first time I've come across this when working with linked lists as I have used a similar setup to work with singly linked lists with no problems.

If anybody could point me in the right direction that would be great.

Comment: You can use compositon. In your __init__ method, call self.node= Node()

Comment: Could you expand on this further please?

Comment: You have two classes: one is called Node and another is called LDL. You need to call the Node class from the LDL class. One easy way to do this is to use the oop concept called composition (you can google it). You can do this by assigning a Node object to a variable like this: self.variable_name = Node() in your __init__ method. The reason we put it there is because that's the first thing being generated when creating an object for LDL class. Your problem deals with object oriented programming (oop) which can be easily googled to understand basic concepts.

Comment: Thanks, I'll investigate composition. What's confusing me mostly is that this is the first time this problem has occurred in the many times I've dealt with both classes. For example in the same function, with no discernible differences, example "nodeCurrent = self.head" works fine yet "nodeActual = self.head" does not.

Comment: Has your question been answered, or are you still looking for an answer?

Answer (score 0):

because your init method of LDL class allows head to be None.
Therefore nodeFirst and nodeLast may become None.
to prevent this fix following

```
def __init__(self, head=None):
    self.head=head
```

to this

```
def __init__(self, headdata):
    self.head=Node(headdata)
```

or alternatively consider the edge case of list size = 0 in reverseSwap method

Comment: Why is it that it is only causing a problem for this one particular time I try to create a node object and set it to the head? For example nodeCurrent = self.head works fine.

Comment: @James if it somehow works then maybe nodeFirst.data is also fine, but nodeLast.data is problematic. consider adding nodeLast=self.head in init method. Or put 'print(i)' statement right before the line of error to see on which iteration the error is raised. if i=0 then it's likely something is wrong with initialization